# Create a UI element placeholder in a window and load a UI element in that placeholder during runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In a WPF window, I want to create a placeholder and during the runtime I would like to render or load a UI element in it.
A placeholder in a window looks something like,

```
<Grid>
   <Placeholder1/>
</Grid>
```

during the runtime, I would like an IconImage to be rendered there.

```
<Placeholder1>
   <Image Source="pack//...." Loaded="Icon_Loaded" />  // Static source
</Placeholder1>
```

I wish to render the placeholder with the Image during runtime everytime I change Image's property, which should eventually trigger the Icon_Loaded event. I dont want to render the Image(Placeholder) on the startup, but later on.

**Background story as to why I wish for a placeholder solution is,**
in the below part of XAML part, I wish to trigger the Loaded event handler everytime I change the IconPack's binding property. So as a solution I reckoned, if I render the IconPack element in a placeholder during the runtime everytime I change its binding property, I get to trigger the Loaded event handler for every binding property change.

```
<IconPack:PackIconFontAwesome Grid.Column="2" Kind="{Binding cbCheckButtonCaptionIconType}"
                                              Foreground="{Binding cbCheckButtonCaptionIconColor}" 
                                              Visibility="{Binding cbCheckButtonCaptionIsVisible}"
                                              Loaded="PackIconFontAwesome_Loaded"/>
```

Could you please show me how to use ContentControl to do the same.
(I tried using TargetUpdated, but it doesnt help in my scenario, so the only option I have is Loaded)

Comment: There is element called `ContentControl` which can display different Content

Comment: In case it's only about images, just use an `Image` element, and set its `Source` property at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you are trying to do. If your are always using images, use the `Image` control and bind the source to a property on your view model that contains the path.

```
private string _imagePath;

public string ImagePath
{
   get => _imagePath;
   set
   {
      if (_imagePath == value)
         return;

      _imagePath = value;
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ImagePath));
   }
}
```

```
<Grid>
   <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath, TargetNullValue={x:Null}}" />
</Grid>
```

For more complex content, usually you would use a [`ContentControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol?view=net-5.0). It has  a [`Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content?view=net-5.0) property that you can assign any controls or bind to a property on a view model. It can be used with data templates (if you are not using data templates, you could also use other controls as placeholder, e.g. a `Border`.).

If you are directly assigning a control to the placeholder in code-behind, it could look like this.

```
<Grid>
   <ContentControl x:Name="Placeholder" />
</Grid>
```

```
Placeholder.Content = new Image(...) {...};
```

If you want to bind a property on a view model and leverage data templating, you could create types:

```
public class ImageItem
{
   public ImageItem(string path)
   {
      Path = path;
   }

   public string Path { get; }
}
```

```
ImagePath = ...;
```

Expose a property for the content item in your view model and assign it, e.g.:

```
public object ContentItem
{
   get => _contentItem;
   set
   {
      if (_contentItem == value)
         return;

      _contentItem = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
   }
}
```

```
ContentItem = new ImageItem(...);
```

Then you could create a `DataTemplate` for this concrete type in XAML.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ImageItem}">
   <Image Source="{Binding Path, TargetNullValue={x:Null}}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

The resources must be in scope of the `ContentControl`, then it will automatically select the appropriate data template for the type bound to the `Content` property.

```
<Grid>
   <ContentControl Content="{Binding ContentItem}" />
</Grid>
```

---

As you want to change the content at runtime, please be aware that it is essential to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) when binding to properties, otherwise changes to properties will not be reflected in the user interface.

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed solution. I am sorry, I should reframe the question. I am looking to render the whole block of Placeholder during the runtime. My intention here is to trigger the Loaded event during the runtime when the Image(static) gets rendered.

Comment: also, it would be generous if an other control like Border for the placeholder could be used in above example. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @r0ckj I am not sure if I understand your intention. The XAML markup, e.g. placeholder and `Image` are loaded when the corresponding control or window is shown and rendered, which means this already happens at runtime. When the `Image` was loaded, it will trigger the `Loaded` event. I think, you should describe what you are actually trying to do, what problem you want to solve. This could be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: I have updated the question. I dearly hope you understand my intention of using placeholder solution for my scenario. If your solution is already addressing my concern, then I am mostly placing the placeholder part somewhere wrong

Comment: thanks it worked, I just had to put things in the right places.